# Remove dictionaries from list where there is more than one with the same hour and minute?

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries which have a date string within them. I would like to remove a single entry of two if there is a matching hour and minute for that record.

Here is some sample data, as you can see the first two dictionaries have 14:21 in them, I would only like one of those dictionaries and the other to be removed.

I'm not sure how to even start with this one, is it possible?

```
[{'x': '2018-06-19 14:21:22', 'y': 80},
{'x': '2018-06-19 14:21:26', 'y': 86},
{'x': '2018-06-19 14:24:02', 'y': 89},
{'x': '2018-06-19 14:24:07', 'y': 95},
{'x': '2018-06-19 14:25:10', 'y': 127}]
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You could, for example, parse the strings to datetimes, compare the hour and minute parts, and implement some logic to decide which one (first?) should end up in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one approach using a simple iteration and a check list.

**Demo:**

```
checkVal = set()
data = [{'x': '2018-06-19 14:21:22', 'y': 80}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:21:26', 'y': 86}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:24:02', 'y': 89}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:24:07', 'y': 95}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:25:10', 'y': 127}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:25:14', 'y': 138}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:28:04', 'y': 91}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:28:08', 'y': 83}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:30:11', 'y': 92}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:30:16', 'y': 99}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:31:21', 'y': 80}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:31:26', 'y': 90}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:34:03', 'y': 131}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:34:07', 'y': 137}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:35:28', 'y': 98}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:35:32', 'y': 91}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:37:11', 'y': 86}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:37:16', 'y': 92}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:39:02', 'y': 111}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:39:06', 'y': 118}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:42:03', 'y': 95}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:42:08', 'y': 104}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:43:04', 'y': 165}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:43:09', 'y': 168}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:45:11', 'y': 89}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:45:15', 'y': 94}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:47:11', 'y': 133}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:47:16', 'y': 146}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:49:16', 'y': 134}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:49:21', 'y': 146}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:52:05', 'y': 157}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:52:09', 'y': 169}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:54:13', 'y': 66}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:54:17', 'y': 63}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:55:09', 'y': 95}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:55:14', 'y': 90}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:58:02', 'y': 112}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:58:07', 'y': 119}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:59:09', 'y': 98}, {'x': '2018-06-19 14:59:13', 'y': 91}]

res = []
for i in data:
    if i["x"][:-3] not in checkVal:
        res.append(i)
        checkVal.add(i["x"][:-3])
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'y': 80, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:21:22'}, {'y': 89, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:24:02'}, {'y': 127, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:25:10'}, {'y': 91, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:28:04'}, {'y': 92, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:30:11'}, {'y': 80, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:31:21'}, {'y': 131, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:34:03'}, {'y': 98, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:35:28'}, {'y': 86, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:37:11'}, {'y': 111, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:39:02'}, {'y': 95, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:42:03'}, {'y': 165, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:43:04'}, {'y': 89, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:45:11'}, {'y': 133, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:47:11'}, {'y': 134, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:49:16'}, {'y': 157, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:52:05'}, {'y': 66, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:54:13'}, {'y': 95, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:55:09'}, {'y': 112, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:58:02'}, {'y': 98, 'x': '2018-06-19 14:59:09'}]
```

Comment: so simple! i like it! In my head it was way more complicated!

Comment: Should be `check_val` but +1 anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

You already have an answer, but for a very efficient solution use the itertools `unique_everseen` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). It's also safer since it will throw a useful error if the input date isn't valid.

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import filterfalse

input_ = [{'x': '2018-06-19 14:21:22', 'y': 80},
          {'x': '2018-06-19 14:21:26', 'y': 86},
          {'x': '2018-06-19 14:24:02', 'y': 89},
          {'x': '2018-06-19 14:24:07', 'y': 95},
          {'x': '2018-06-19 14:25:10', 'y': 127}]

def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    """List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen.
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    """
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element

def hour_and_min(dct):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    d = datetime.strptime(dct['x'], fmt)
    return d.hour, d.minute  # add `, d.year, d.month, d.day` if you care about these

output = list(unique_everseen(input_, key=hour_and_min))
```

---

And output is:

```
[{'x': '2018-06-19 14:21:22', 'y': 80},
 {'x': '2018-06-19 14:24:02', 'y': 89},
 {'x': '2018-06-19 14:25:10', 'y': 127}]
```